# Selenium driver for remote browser

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, selenium-webdriver

I am using selenium-webdriver and running this test on a remote machine.

I want to redirect the user to the mobile website by changing the user agent.

I tried with the following, but it doesn't work.

```
require 'selenium-webdriver'

capabilities = Selenium::WebDriver::Remote::Capabilities.firefox(:firefox_profile => 'Mozilla/5.0(iPad; U; CPU iPhone OS 3_2 like Mac OS X; en-us) AppleWebKit/531.21.10 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0.4 Mobile/7B314 Safari/531.21.10')

browser = Selenium::WebDriver.for :remote, :desired_capabilities => capabilities

browser.get "http://mobile.website.com/"
```

I am getting this error on my browser

```
Selenium::WebDriver::Error::WebDriverError (Could not find Firefox binary (os=linux). Make sure Firefox is installed or set the path manually with Selenium::WebDriver::Firefox::Binary.path=):
```

a. Is there any way to achieve this without using selenium?

b. Is there any way to detect the user's browser and redirect the user to URL with the mobile user agent string(iphone,android)?

Answer (score 0):

Why not test your website in a real mobile device, e.g. using Appium.

You can use Appium to drive the browser in your mobile.